# How can I specify the flatten layer input size after many conv layers in PyTorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Here is my problem, I do a small test on CIFAR10 dataset, how can I specify the flatten layer input size in PyTorch? like the following, the input size is 16*5*5, however I don't know how to calculate this and I want to get the input size through some function.Can someone just write a simple function in this Net class and solve this?

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,6,5)  
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6,16,5)

        # HERE , the input size is 16*5*5, but I don't know how to get it.
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120,84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)),(2,2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)),2)
        x = x.view(x.size()[0],-1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch - Inferring linear layer in\_features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262712/pytorch-inferring-linear-layer-in-features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Flatten Layer in the Pytorch default. You can create a class like below. Cheers

```
class Flatten(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        return input.view(input.size(0), -1)


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.flatten   = Flatten()  ## describing the layer
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3,6,5)  
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6,16,5)

        # HERE , the input size is 16*5*5, but I don't know how to get it.
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120,84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)),(2,2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)),2)
        #x = x.view(x.size()[0],-1)
        x = self.flatten(x)   ### using of flatten layer
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Comment: wait…the problem is still there. Although using your self defined flatten layer, I still need to specify the input size of fc1, which is 16*5*5.

Comment: @gaoquanliang you can't do this. That means "I want to change the graph for each iteration"  in that case model can't learn anything. There is no option like that in any framework. AFAIK

Comment: In other words, can you tell me something about how to get the input size of fc1 16*5*5 ?

Comment: @gaoquanliang take a look what is convolution layer, kernel size etc. You should understand how layers change

Answer (score 1):

Just answering to update this post, there is now a `nn.Flatten()` layer in Pytorch as of 1.3:

> https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/flatten.html

Also, worth mentioning that if you can't use >=1.3 and you "need" that CNN output size (for example if you have multiple heads, most people do programmatically get the output from a dummy input, with something like:

```py
def get_flat_fts(self, input_shape, conv_net):
    f = conv_net(Variable(torch.ones(1,*input_shape)))
    return int(np.prod(f.size()[1:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite this is old, I'll answer for future readers. 5x5 is the image dimension after all the convolutions and poolings. In the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d), there is a formula to compute this: 
Hight_out = (Hight_in + 2*padding - dilation*(kernel_size-1)-1)/stride +1. It's the same for the width.
So you start with a 32x32 image. After the first convolution layer, you got a 28x28 image because of the kernel size (you lost 2 pixels on each side). After the pooling, you got 14x14, because it is a 2x2 mask with a stride of 2. Then, the second convolution layer gives you a 10x10 image, and finally, the last pooling gives 5x5. Then you multiply for the number of output channels: 16.

I think @trizard answer was close but he misread the kernel size.

Answer (score 0):

The input size for the first FC layer depends on the size of your input. The [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d) tells you what the output size of a Conv2d layer will be for a given input, so you just need to translate that formula to a function. In your case, if your input image is m by n, the input size you're looking for will be 16*(m-8)*(n-8).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bit of code of the pytorch tutorial right ?
I have got the same problem and Jens Petersen is right : the input size of the fully-connected (FC) layer depends on the input-size and the operations you performed on it before the FC-layer. In your case, you forgot to take into account the max-pooling steps.
As this network is built to take 32x32 inputs, the first convulational layer outputs a 6 * (32-3) * (32-3) which gives us after maxpooling 6 * floor(29/2) * floor(29/2) = 6 * 14 * 14. And after second conv-layer + max pooling we have an output of size 16 * 5 * 5.