# Pytorch - Inferring linear layer in_features

Tags: python, pytorch

I am building a toy model to take in some images and give me a classification. My model looks like:

`conv2d -> pool -> conv2d -> linear -> linear`.

My issue is that when we create the model, we have to calculate the size of the first linear layer `in_features` based on the size of the input image. If we get new images of different sizes, we have to recalculate `in_features` for our linear layer. Why do we have to do this? Can't it just be inferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 1.8, PyTorch now has [`LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html) which infers the input dimension:

> A `torch.nn.Linear` module where *in_features* is inferred.

Comment: Thank you, I got used to calculating it but this is excellent that they have included this.

Answer (score 0):

oh,I also meet the situation and  there is my solution

```
    output3=torch.flatten(output1) # flatten the tensor
    output3_1=output3.clone().detach()
```

#create a new tensor,whos require_graid=Flase

```
    output4=output3_1.numpy()ndarry #turn the tensor to ndarry
    self.size=np.size(output4)
```

#get the size of the ndarry   self.size will be a int calss
now you get the value of in_feature