# Linear layer input size Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm working on an assignement with 1D signals and I have trouble finding the right input size for the linear layer (XXX). My signals have different lengths and are padded in a batch. I read that the linear layear should always have the same input size (XXX) but I'm not sure how to find it when each batch has a different length. Does anybody have an advice?
Thanks

```
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        
        
        self.features = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv1d(in_channels = 1, out_channels = 128, kernel_size = 7, stride = 3), 
                                      nn.BatchNorm1d(128),
                                      nn.ReLU(),
                                      nn.MaxPool1d(2, 3), 
                                      nn.Conv1d(128, 32, 5, 1), 
                                      nn.BatchNorm1d(32),
                                      nn.ReLU(),
                                      nn.MaxPool1d(2, 2),
                                      nn.Conv1d(32, 32, 5, 1),
                                      nn.ReLU(),
                                      nn.Conv1d(32, 128, 3, 2),
                                      nn.ReLU(),
                                      nn.MaxPool1d(2, 2),
                                      nn.Conv1d(128, 256, 7, 1), 
                                      nn.ReLU(),
                                      nn.MaxPool1d(2, 2),
                                      nn.Conv1d(256, 512, 3, 1),
                                      nn.ReLU(),
                                      nn.Conv1d(512, 128, 3, 1),
                                      nn.ReLU()
                                      )
        
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(XXX, 512),
                                        nn.ReLU(),
                                        nn.Dropout(p = 0.1),
                                        nn.Linear(512,2)
                                        )
          
    def forward(self, x):
        
        x = self.features(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        
        return x
```

Comment: Each batch cannot be of a different shape. You need to have a fixed size input length, for ex: 512. When you read the values whose length is less than 512, say 256, you can pad it and then send it to the network. Also, instead of using `torch.flatten()`, do this: `x = x.view(-1, x.size(1) * x.size(2))`. Then print the shape of `x` in your forward method, find it's shape and then set the size of the input layer as shown by the shape of x.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So if I understand correctly, ALL the signals need to have the same length? Because now I pad only signals in each batch (so for example batch size is 5 and all the 5 signals in one batch have for example length 1000, in a different batch all the 5 signals have length 1200 etc.). Because the differences in signal lengths are big and I don't want to pad too much so I always find the longest signal in each batch and pad it that way.

Comment: You're correct. Each signal within a batch needs to be of the same length. Even if 1 signal within a batch has a different length, the output shapes from each Conv layer would differ w.r.t. other signals (who are of the same length) and you'll get an error at your linear layer.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought. But I actually spent quite a lot of time figuring out how to pass the size of x from the forward method to XXX (nn.Linear(XXX, 512)). Do you have any idea how to do it? I tried many different ways but none worked :/

Comment: Yes, there are ways of solving this. I have written an answer, check it and let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch - Inferring linear layer in\_features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262712/pytorch-inferring-linear-layer-in-features)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to decide on a fixed-length input. Let's assume each signal is of length 2048. It didn't work for any `length < 1024` because of the previous convolution layers. If you would like to have a signal of `length < 1024`, then you may need to either remove a couple of Convolutional layers or change the `kernel_size` or remove `maxpool` operation.

Assuming, the fixed length is 2048, your `nn.Linear` layer will take as input 768 neurons. To calculate this, fix an arbitrary size of input neurons to your `nn.Linear` layer (say 1000) and then try to print the shape of the output from the Conv. layers. You could do something like this in your forward call:

```py
def forward(self, x):
        
    x = self.features(x)
    print('Output shape of Conv. layers', x.shape)

    x = x.view(-1, x.size(1) * x.size(2))
    print('Shape required to pass to Linear Layer', x.shape)

    x = self.classifier(x)
    
    return x
```

This will obviously throw an error because of the shape mismatch. But you'll get to know the number of input neurons required in your first `nn.Linear` layer. With this approach, you could try a number of experiments of varying input signal lengths (1536, 2048, 4096, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! It seems I managed to solve the problem :)

Comment: Glad to hear..!